# How can I set the deserialization type of arriving objects, based on the Content-Type header?

Tags: asp.net, http, serialization, asp.net-web-api

How can I select the serialization format for objects arriving to a Web API service, based on the Content-Type of the Http message?

For example, I want to deserialize the arriving text as JSON, if the Content-Type is `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it inside your WebApi method then with following you can do it.

```
switch(Request.Headers["Content-type"])
        {
            case "x-www-form-urlencoded":
                {
                    //Use json deserializer
                    break;
                }
            case "xyz":
                {
                    //Use xyz deserializer
                    break;
                }
            case "abc":
                {
                    //Use abc deserializer
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    //Do nothing
                    break;
                }
        }
```

However if you want to deserialize parameters to api method based on content-type then you need to use custom model binders.
Read more about mode binders [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)